# Android scrolling inside HTML containers, which has a CSS overflow property

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have a container on a page, which has has a huge overflow-x. On a iPad, the user can simple swipe-scroll left, just like they would do vertically when scrolling down the page.

On a PC, scrollbars are visible so the user can scroll left and right.

However, on the Android, no scroll bars appear and I can't swipe left like I can on the iPad.

Is some special CSS and JS needed here? Does anyone know *why* this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overflow property is not working properly in Android devices before Android 3.0. But it is solved from the Android 3.0 or later.

I also had this issue while I was developing an application.

This issue was solved by using a button and animating the element's margin-top property so that it is changed to negative value, therefore creating a scroll effect.